# Check if server supports https with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on an userscript where I'd like to see if the server supports HTTPS, and if it does then I'll redirect the user to it with `location.href`.

I had cases where https is supported, but when the user follows a link without https:// on it they get sent to a http page. I've seen this happen on all Stack Exchange websites, where you click on the answers linked on Google and you are redirected to a http link, however if you change the link by hand you get https.

Currently what I'm doing is sending a `XMLHttpRequest` to a https version of the link (something like `location.href.replace("http://", "https://")`), and after the request is finished I'll check if I got a valid response or not.

This works, but I'd like to know if there is a better way (something like asking the server if he can handle https), since sometimes the https request I'm sending takes a long time to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is redirection on server side

Comment: But a userscript runs only on the client side.

Comment: Yep, this is going to be a script that will be injected to the page on client-side.